# NGINX append location directive to proxy_pass url?

Tags: nginx, domain, reverse-proxy

My nginx.conf

```
location /admin/ {
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass https://myproxydomain.com:3000;

      }
```

I would like to have  all my pages from mentioned proxy_pass url, as 
https://subdomain.example.com/admin/sign

But the moment, I was trying to access *signin* page (signin page which is in proxy_pass url), it is serving as 
https://subdomain.example.com/sign

Any inputs would be appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by redirect here.

Comment: HTTP redirection.  Way to point one domain or address to another.

Comment: So do you mean that when you try the `/admin/sign` URL, there is a redirect to `/sign`? That is not caused by the configuration you have above, but by the application you are running.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen, sorry for my poor english. Please read the question again, I edited it.

Comment: The question is still a bit unclear.. Do you mean that the URLs from the HTML files provided by ´proxy_pass` server contain `https://subdomain.example.com/sign`? If that is the case, then you need to change the application there, nginx does not support changing the HTML output from `proxy_pass` servers.

Comment: Okay. I I will try again
1. For specific location (i.e, /admin/) I am adding proxy_pass with certain url 
2. Now ideally, all pages from proxy_pass, prepend with this location variable. 


I would like to prepand my location variable (i.e, /admin/) to every request that I make on proxy_pass

Comment: Please look at section :2 here at specified URL 
https://www.liaohuqiu.net/posts/nginx-proxy-pass/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work:

```
location /admin {
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass https://myproxydomain.com:3000/admin/;# 
}
```

If that does not work, then you can use a regex capture:

```
location ~ /admin(.*) {
    ...
    proxy_pass https://myproxydomain.com:3000/admin$1;
}
```

Comment: both didn't work for me. thanks in advance. 

I have a point to make here, 
proxy_pass https://myproxydomain.com:3000/admin/;

This URL doesn't work exist right! . Because /admin/ we are prepending from NGINX location directive.